# LESS optimize vs. minify CSS file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, less, assets, minify

Have never done this before, so my understanding may be totally off. I understand that LESS optimizes and minifies your CSS. So... is it better to just use LESS or should you still minify your files some how?

Feel free to raise other differences that I don't know about.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding what LESS is.

Comment: I'd agree with that, would you like to help clarify?

Comment: Certain Less compilers provide an option to minify their output CSS too but this is no more than just a subtle bonus feature actually having nothing to do with Less itself (more over in most cases to minify the resulting CSS such Less compiler actually uses the same or similar external minifier library you'd use to minify your CSS w/o Less). These ambiguous terms are often quite confusing: "Optimization", "Minification". When you read something like "Less let you to optimize your code" it usually literally means the code *you write* not a minification of the CSS that your code will compile to.

Comment: @seven-phases-max so i'm curious, if I use a Less compiler that has a bonus feature of minifying the output CSS, then this basically means that I would not have to minify it again using something like sass right? It just seems to me like I can achieve two things using one Less compiler rather than compiler + post processor

Comment: both less and sass are preprocessor you should use only one of them. the less compiler has the `--compress` option. This option only removes whitespaces and does not any other optimisation. The clean-css plugin can also do some optimisation like selector merging.

Comment: @BassJobsen Got it, so if you do less compiler with `--compress` could you recommend to still use something like `clean-css` plugin afterward?

Answer (score 1):

Less is a preprocessor, it compiles into static CSS. Less enables you to use variables and mixins which help you to write DRY and reusable code.

Example:

CSS:

```
p {
color:red;
}
h1 {
color: red;
}
```

Less:

```
@color: red;

p {
color: @color;
}

h1 {
color: @color;
}
```

If you want to use `yellow` instead of `red` you only have to change `@color: red;` now.

The same for mixins, Less:

```
.default-style() {
color: @color;
border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
.default-style();
}

h1 {
.default-style();
}
```

If you do not need a border for your default style any more, you will only have to remove the `border` property from the `.default-style()` mixin.

Less does not minify or optimize your (comiled) CSS code.

Since Less 2 you can use plugins that postprocess your compiled CSS code. This plugins can minify / compress or optimize your code.

For instance use clean-css (https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css) for compressing and CSScomb (https://github.com/bassjobsen/less-plugin-csscomb) for optimizing.